# Nilpotency of Lie algebra from structure constants

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider a given set of structure constants $c_{ij}^k$ defining a (finite dimensional) Lie algebra $\mathfrak{L}$, i.e.
$$[e_i,e_j] = \sum_{k=1}^N c_{i,j}^k \, e_k  \qquad i,j=1,\ldots,N$$
with $N$ denoting the dimension of $\mathfrak{L}$.
In terms of the $c_{i,j}^k$ the adjoint representation of the 
basis element $e_i$ is the matrix
$$ ad(e_i) \; = \; \begin{pmatrix}c_{i,1}^1 & \ldots & c_{i,N}^1\\
\vdots & & \vdots\\
c_{i,1}^N & \ldots & c_{i,N}^N\end{pmatrix}
\qquad i=1,\ldots,N
$$ 
Assuming the sequence 
$$[ad(e_1),[ad(e_2),[\ldots[ad(e_{N-1}),ad(e_N)]]]] = 0$$
vanishes, is it correct to conclude that $\mathfrak{L}$ is nilpotent?
([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_Lie_algebra) describes the required length of the sequence as "sufficiently large". Is $N$ sufficiently large?)

Comment: You need more N-fold commutators to vanish, namely, all N-fold commutators where we are using all orders of generators and even using some generators repeatedly. Just think of commutative case. With this in mind, the proof us a simple induction on N.